# NSOutlineView how to show blue outline during right click

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, appkit, nsoutlineview

Everyone discussed about how to get rid of the blue outline during right click... but me.

Instead, **I'm trying to display the blue outline.**

I didn't get any outline when I right clicked my outline view row. The menu appeared but the outline wasn't. 
You can see that the blue outline is not visible in this picture below:

[image]

---

Below is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Blue outline]

---

**Update**

This is how I implemented the `NSMenu`. I subclassed the `NSOutlineView` and made a new protocol to override `NSOutlineViewDelegate`.

This idea was to make it simple by letting the `NSOutlineView` ask the `NSMenu` for each item, so we can implement different menu for each item. It works but the blue outline view doesn't show up during right click.

**KRMenuOutlineView.swift**

```
import Cocoa

@objc protocol KRMenuOutlineViewDelegate: NSOutlineViewDelegate {
    // This method will ask NSMenu for each item in outline view
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: KRMenuOutlineView, menuFor item: Any, event: NSEvent) -> NSMenu?
}

class KRMenuOutlineView: NSOutlineView {

    override var delegate: NSOutlineViewDelegate? {
        didSet {
            if let newValue = delegate {
                /*
                 * Swift doesn't support overriding inherited properties with different type
                 * like Objective C Does, therefore we need internal delegate.
                 */
                internalDelegate = unsafeBitCast(newValue, to: KRMenuOutlineViewDelegate.self)
            } else {
                internalDelegate = nil
            }
        }
    }

    private var internalDelegate: KRMenuOutlineViewDelegate?

    override func menu(for event: NSEvent) -> NSMenu? {
        let point = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        if let item = self.item(atRow: self.row(at: point)) {
            return self.internalDelegate?.outlineView(self, menuFor: item, event: event)
        }
        return super.menu(for: event)
    }
}
```

Then, I use it in my view controller like this:

**KRTreeViewController.swift**

```
extension KRTreeViewController: KRMenuOutlineViewDelegate {
    func outlineView(_ outlineView: KRMenuOutlineView, menuFor item: Any, event: NSEvent) -> NSMenu? {
            let menu = NSMenu(title: "Contextual Menu")
            menu.delegate = self

            let key = String(utf16CodeUnits: [unichar(NSBackspaceCharacter)], count: 1) as String
            let deleteMenuItem = menu.addItem(withTitle: "Delete",
                                              action: #selector(didClickMenuItem(_:)),
                                              keyEquivalent: key)
            deleteMenuItem.representedObject = myItem
            deleteMenuItem.target = self

            return menu
    }

    @objc fileprivate func didClickMenuItem(_ menuItem: NSMenuItem) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't know what you did to make the blue outline dissappear. How did you implement the context menu? Did you do anything to alter any default behaviour of `NSOutlineView`?

Comment: @Willeke I updated my question.

Comment: Try calling `super.menu(for: event)` before returning your own menu.

Answer (score 1):

How to properly show a context menu:

If you have created your menu using a storyboard:
First, go to the storyboard and add the menu to the viewController that contains the outlineView.
Then make it an `@IBOutlet` so you can reference it later.

In a method like `viewDidLoad()`, add the menu to the outlineView by calling

```
outlineView.menu = myMenu
```

where myMenu can either be the one you created in Interface Builder or in code.

You can run the app now and should see the blue outline around the cell.

The problem now is that you don't know which cell the user has clicked.
To fix this, set yourself as the delegate of myMenu and adopt the NSMenuDelegate protocol.

```
func menuNeedsUpdate(_ menu: NSMenu) {
    let row = self.outlineView.clickedRow

    guard row != -1 else { return }
    for item in menu.items {
        item.representedObject = row
    }
}
```

Here you can do whatever you need. This implementation sets the rowIndex as the representedObject of each menu item. Keep in mind that this only works on static outlineViews (ones that don't change in the background) and menus which only go one level deep.

You could also store the index or object represented by the cell (if the outlineView is not static) in a local variable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, using this solution, how can we can limit to show menu only for specific item in `NSOutlineView`? I also updated my question showing the code implementation.

Comment: What if I **haven't** created the menu using a storyboard? I have commented out all overrdies in my outline view subclass and the blue outline is still not showing...

Comment: @Nicolas Miari: You can simply create the menu in code. For example, in `viewDidLoad()`, create your menu and call `outlineView.menu = myMenu`. The rest should be as described above.

Comment: @mangerlahn Yes, thank you; I figured out that in the end. I added an NSMenu with one dummy item, then overrode `menu(for:)` to have cell-specific menues. Overriding alone would not work; the menu property has to be set to a non-empty menu.